# How do I exit this method?

Tags: java, recursion, intellij-idea, tree

I am trying to find the parent of a node in binary tree and return the parent node.

```
public static Node findParent(Node root, Node child) {

    while(true) {

        if(root.left == child || root.right == child){
            break;
        }

        if (root.left != null) {
            findParent(root.left, child);
        }

        if (root.right != null) {
            findParent(root.right, child);
        }
    }
    return  root;
}
```

When I find the parent, it returns the parent node but after executing the return statement, the method still executes infinitely. Can someone explain what's going on?
Also, is there more efficient to find the parent node and return it?

Comment: Well, `root` and `child` will be the same for one call of the method, so if `root.left == child` etc. aren't true the first time it won't be true in any further iterations and thus your loop never ends. You're never changing `root` or `child` in the method. Also note that because of this `return root` will return the parameter passed to the first call, so you'd gain nothing here.

Comment: It's a great opportunity to discover debug features of your IDE. Set a breakpoint. Execute your findParent line by line and check why the execution never ends.

Comment: You are trying to combine the recursive and iterative approaches. If you go with recursion, you don't need the `while`.

Comment: The root is changed in the recursive calls, so it's basically checking children of every node and if it matches with the child parameter then it returns the parent. I've checked the method in the debugger and it returns the parent correctly but the problem is the method execution won't stop after the parent is returned

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you have a `while` loop. Then, for every child who enter into the method will be iterating into the loop.

You have to think that the recursion is 'like a loop', so yo don't need another one.

The recursion only need to find the value one time, and then 'go back' through the methods that have called it and return.

Comment: Thank you. my understanding of recursion is still vague. :(

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a loop when you are using recursion:

```
public static Node findParent(Node root, Node child) {
    Node parent = null;

    if (root.left == child || root.right == child) {
        parent = root;
    } else {
        if (root.left != null) {
            parent = findParent(root.left, child);
        }

        if (parent == null && root.right != null) {
            parent = findParent(root.right, child);
        }
    }
    return parent; // null means child is not in the tree 
}
```

Comment: That worked. I always thought that recursive calls should be in a loop in order to come to the base case so I never thought about this. Thank you:)